# Using .htaccess to change my website URLs

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some pages organised like this:

```
http://localhost/index.html
http://localhost/download.html
http://localhost/contact.html
```

And I need them changed to suit the following URL structure:

```
http://localhost/
http://localhost/download
http://localhost/contact
```

Without making sub directories and putting in pages as `index.html`. As far as I know .htaccess can be used for this, but I have no idea what I need to add to my .htaccess file to make this work.

Can anyone provide some help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [this](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html)? Here's [another page](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php). And here's [a discussion about it](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/2545.htm).

Comment: Kind of, although I have no experience in this stuff so it doesn't make much sense lol. Although now I know what to google for, I should be able to find something. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. It doesn't look too hard to achieve. You might want to read the discussion link. Good luck.